# Is there a way to turn analog cameras into ip cameras?

Tags: camera, ip-camera, network-camera, surveillance, home-surveillance

I've got 8 Monacor analog cameras which I used to connect to a Geovision capture Card now the Card is broken.
So I was thinking if there is a way to connect them to my Synology DS214+.

Comment: Sure. Connect to a dedicated PC (or SBC) with a (composite) video digitizer/encoder, a network interface and conversion software.  IOW the "analog" video camera is useless with a digital computer without a capture card or equivalent, e.g. a video-to-MPEG converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to convert the analogue video into a digital stream before you can use it either with the Surveillance Station or simply to store it to hard drive.

Synology publish a list of supported video servers for Surveillance Station I believe and they include the Axis range and at least some from Vivotek.

To handle 8 analogue streams will always require something special as that is a lot of data that has to be handled and converted.

Comment: On the Surveillance Station IP camera Support List page there is checkbox that lets you shortlist video servers if you expand the advanced features section: https://www.synology.com/en-uk/compatibility/camera?brand=all&videoserver